# FabricJS: is there a way to make object unselectable outside of clip mask?

Tags: fabricjs

I am creating grid on fabric canvas, where the user can upload images in each cell of a grid. Each cell has a clipping mask, and everything is fine. But my problem is, that if the user moves an image in one cell you can see selection outside of the clipping mask. Is there a way to keep the selection inside clipping mask?
[here is a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktPOf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add in your canvas options the next option `controlsAboveOverlay: true`

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {
  controlsAboveOverlay: true
});
```

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#controlsAboveOverlay

**Edit:**
Added an example with `perPixelTargetFind` option

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-shtern-hq20u?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Looks like that controlsAboveOverlay don't work for me, tried both true and false.
I took a screenshot to better represent my problem
https://i.imgur.com/69OTmsY.jpg

Comment: @Entropy I've added an example for you in my answer above. And it works fine. Could you explain what behavior you expect? And I'll try to help you

Comment: I think I've understood now your problem

Comment: That's exactly what I need to achieve, but I need to have clipPath on each cell, not on canvas. So that when the user moves or scale image in one cell he can still select other cells. as you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/uYMeyKE.jpg), image selection goes over clip-path

Comment: @Entropy can you see my example now with `perPixelTargetFind` option

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed it for me!